# Paypal Batch Payout behavior on item error

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

With the batch payout API for Paypal, if I send a request with multiple items and there is an error with one of them, will the ones without an error still go through? Or will they all fail?

For example, if I sent a payload of:

```
{
"sender_batch_header": {
    "sender_batch_id": "batch_8",
    "email_subject": "You have a payment"
},
"items": [
    {
        "recipient_type": "EMAIL",
        "amount": {
            "value": 1.0,
            "currency": "USD"
        },
        "receiver": "test_user@example.com",
        "note": "Thank you.",
        "sender_item_id": "item_1"
    },
    {
        "recipient_type": "EMAIL",
        "amount": {
            "value": 1.0,
            "currency": "USD"
        },
        "receiver": "bad_email_address",
        "note": "Thank you.",
        "sender_item_id": "item_1"
    }]
}
```

Will the payout to test_user@example.com go through since the other item has an invalid email address?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you use

"receiver": "bad_email_address",

PayPal will throw out error as "bad_email_address" is not in email format, the whole payout can't go through, no money sent out.

If you use

"receiver": "bad_email_address@email.com",

The email address is not existed, but it's email format, the whole payment will go through, existed PayPal receiver will get the money, this un-existed email transaction will in Unclaimed status. If someone register this email address, then this person will get the money.